# Quaternion.Lerp not working properly in Unity3d

Tags: unity, unityscript, quaternion, lerp

I'm using `Quaternion.Lerp` to rotate a joint with a certain angle, but when I use the below code I find the joint rotating very far although I specified it to rotate with only 5. Any thoughts please?

```
Vector3 newRot.y += currentTransform.localRotation.y + 5f;
blendWeight = 0;
if ( blendWeight < 1)
{
    animationRotation = currentTransform.transform.localRotation;
    newRotation = Quaternion.Euler(newRot.x, newRot.y, newRot.z);
    blendWeight += Time.deltaTime/0.9f;
    currentTransform.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp (animationRotation,newRotation, blendWeight);
}
```

Comment: Only 5 _what_? 5 radians is a large fraction of a circle.

Comment: @SethBattin I want it 5 degrees.

Comment: How are you calling your code?

Comment: It's in the lateupdate function

Comment: So you're calling this every frame.  Did you intend to only move it 5 units one time?

Comment: yes, this is what I did

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26781/discussion-between-tak-and-seth-battin).

Comment: know your units, 1 radian is ~ 60° so 5 radians is ~300° degrees

Comment: One glaring problem here is this line: `Vector3 newRot.y += currentTransform.localRotation.y + 5f;` — you're forming an Euler angle vector using the y component of a Quaternion. This is unlikely to have the geometric meaning you intend. If you're trying to inherit the yaw component of localRotation, then `localRotation.eulerAngles.y` is closer but still fraught at certain angles because of the way Euler angles jump around near gimble lock points. It's generally safer to work in quaternions for incremental rotations, and only use Euler angles for absolute orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Try decreasing the amount of the rotation, so change 5 to a lower number like 2, if that's still a lot decrease it even more.